# updating app for iphone 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

So in trying to update my currently iOS 7 application that was created with the old Xcode 5 storyboard to be optimized for the iPhone 6, I'm running into some issues. I read that it's necessary to add the launch images for the iPhone 6 and 6+ in order for it to properly size the views.

I was able to convert an app created for iOS 7 inside Xcode 6 with the new storyboards and it was simply a matter of adding those launch images.

I tried adding the launch images to the former application and upon launch of any device, Xcode crashes. So I went into the storyboard, and converted the whole thing to the new storyboard format. Added the launch images again and it's still crashing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exception is raised? What stack trace is provided?

Comment: the app doesn't crash. Xcode crashes. There's no error report either.

Comment: I've obviously become too used to people being very approximate in their language (English isn't everybody's first though, so fair enough); apologies for that. Since it sounds like an Xcode bug to which the answer is going to be "I randomly tried tweaking this", is there any way you can provide the project? Or is it private?

Comment: A little late on my response, I thought I could fix it on my own. I think I can provide the project. Can I PM you or something? The issue is purely storyboard because I've created a new project and have only done work in storyboard and i'm crashing again.